# Mapbox how to query for the features which are available in current view port?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I want to use mapbox's queryRenderedFeatures API which will give me the set of "visible" features satisfying the given query parameters.

Does this gives the feature set from current map viewport only? If not then how do I fetch the features from current viewport only?

Is there any way where I can provide x,y coordinate bounds of a map viewport to queryRenderedFeatures API?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this gives the features from the current viewport only.

You can get a subset of those features by giving a bounding box with the geometry parameter. See the [documentation for this functon](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#queryrenderedfeatures).

> Omitting this parameter (i.e. calling Map#queryRenderedFeatures with zero arguments, or with only a options argument) is equivalent to passing a bounding box encompassing the entire map viewport.